# OCaml: Function input ('a * 'b -> 'c)

Tags: function, ocaml

```
let rec 

map2 (f : 'a * 'b -> 'c) (l1 : 'a list) (l2 : 'b list) : 'c list =
  match (l1,l2) with
    | ([], []) -> []
    | (x::l1),(y::l2) -> f (x, y)::(map2 f (l1, l2))
```

It is returning:

```
Error: This expression has type 'a list * 'a list
   but an expression was expected of type 'a list
```

What am I doing wrong here??

Answer (score 10):

The error is `map2 f (l1, l2)` (as the error location would have told you). You're passing `(l1, l2)` as a tuple while they should be separate curried parameters : `map2 f l1 l2`.

Also, your function does not handle the cases of different length (patterns with one list empty but not the other). In this case, the function will raise a match failure, you may want to raise a more specialized error such as `invalid_arg "map2"` or something.

Comment: F# gives the following warning: Incomplete pattern matches on this expression. For example, the value '(_,[_])' may indicate a case not covered by the pattern(s)

Comment: @manojlds Of course, OCaml also raises a warning. "Warning P: this pattern-matching is not exhaustive. Here is an example of a value that is not matched: (_::_, [])"

Comment: @jlaguatan no it isn't, as `f` has type `('a * 'b) -> 'c`, it takes a couple as parameter.

Comment: Error: This expression has type ('a list -> 'b list) * 'a list
       but an expression was expected of type 'b list ... I'm getting this error still

Comment: @jlaguatan you're doing something wrong. Just making the small replace I gave you works.